# Looping my IF statement in Python Program

Tags: python

Im trying to get my if statement to loop in a chatbot i am creating

This is the code for the chatbot (excluding the dictionaries i used)

```
            print("Hello, I'm The Hypebeast Bot")
        print("I'm here to help you fine the Hypebeast items you want")

        name = input("What is Your Name?\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        print("Hello "+name)

        time.sleep(1)

        choice = input("So what can i help you find today? I know about Shoes, Hoodies and T-Shirts\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        if "Shoes" in choice:
            shoes = input("Okay, what brand of shoes are you looking for?\n")
            if "Nike" in shoes:
                NikeModel = input("Which model are you looking for?\n")
                if NikeModel in NikeModels_db.keys():
                    print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in NikeModels_db[NikeModel]))
                else:
                    print("Sorry I dont know that model")

            elif "Adidas" in shoes:
                AdidiasModel = input("What model are you looking for?\n")
                if AdidasModel in AdidasModels_db():
                    print("You can buy that model from" + " , Or ".join(shop for shop in AdidasModels_db[AdidasModel]))
                else:
                    print("Sorry I dont know that model")

            elif "Puma" in shoes:
                PumaModel = input("What model are you looking for?\n")
                if PumaModel in PumaModels_db():
                    print("You can buy that model from" + " , Or ".join(shop for shop in PumaModels_db[PumaModel]))
                else:
                    print("Sorry I dont know that model")

            elif "Balenciaga" in shoes:
                BalenciagaModel = input("What model are you looking for?\n")
                if BalenciagaModel in BalenicagaModels_db():
                    print("You can buy that model from" + " , Or ".join(shop for shop in BalenicagaModels_db[BalenciagaModel]))
                else:
                    print("Sorry I dont know that model")
            else:
                print("Sorry I dont know that brand")

        elif "Hoodies" in choice:
                hoodie = input("Okay, What brand of hoodie are you looking for?\n")
                if "Supreme" in hoodie:
                    SupremeModel = input("What Kind of Supreme Hoodie are you looking for?\n")
                    if SupremeModel in SupremeHoodie_db():
                        print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in SupremeHoodie_db[SupremeModel]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that model")

                elif "Palace" in hoodie:
                    PalaceModel = input("What Kind of Palace Hoodie are you looking for?\n")
                    if PalceModel in PalaceHoodie_db():
                        print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in PalaceHoodie_db[PalaceModel]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that model")

                elif "Hera" in hoodie:
                    HeraModel = input("What kind of hera hoodie are you looking for?\n")
                    if HeraModel in HeraHoodie_db():
                        print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in HeraHoodie_db[HeraModel]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that model")
                else:
                    print("Sorry I dont know that brand")

        elif "T-Shirts" in choice:
                tshirts = input("Okay, What brand of T-Shirt are you looking for?\n")
                if "Hera" in tshirts:
                    HeraTshirt = input("What kind of hera T-shirt are you looking for?\n")
                    if HeraTshirt in HeraTshirt_db():
                         print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in HeraTshirt_db[HeraTshirt]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that T-Shirt")

                elif "Supreme" in tshirts:
                    SupremeTshirt = input("What kind of Supreme T-shirt are you looking for?\n")
                    if SupremeTshirt in SupremeTshirt_db():
                         print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in SupremeTshirt_db[SupremeTshirt]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that T-Shirt")

                elif "Anti Social Social Club" in tshirts:
                    ASSCTshirt = input("What kind of Anti Social Social Club T-shirt are you looking for?\n")
                    if ASSCTshirt in ASSCshirt_db():
                         print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in ASSCTshirt_db[ASSCTshirt]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that T-Shirt")

                elif "Gucci" in tshirts:
                    GucciTshirt = input("What kind of Gucci T-shirt are you looking for?\n")
                    if GucciTshirt in Guccishirt_db():
                         print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in GucciTshirt_db[GucciTshirt]))
                    else:
                        print("Sorry I dont know that T-Shirt") 
                else:
                     print("Sorry I dont know that brand")

        else:
            print("Sorry, I dont have any information about that.")
```

for example when the user inputs a nike model in the shoes choice that the program doesnt know it will loop back and ask them for the model they are looking for. i tried for loops and while loops but they didnt work unless i used them incorrectly (i no longer have them in the program)

Comment: Can you edit your post to share what you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: @user112828, unfortunately, i no longer have what i tried as i reverted back to standard if statements as they were what worked and i had to demonstrate the code working

Comment: I recommend using version control next time so that you don't lose what you've tried

Comment: Please supply the expected {MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Most of this code has little or nothing to do with your looping control.  Also be *clear* on what you need to do: an `if` statement does not cause a loop.

Comment: You'll have more luck if you write a minimal example that demonstrates your problem without extra fluff. you don't need those prompts or most of those `if`'s to demonstrate the problem. They actually make it harder for us to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, i have declare repeat to true. Then i am checking condition if repeat is true, loop over if statement until repeat is false. The repeat will becomes false, when you find shoe model in dict.

```
repeat = true;
if "Shoes" in choice:
            shoes = input("Okay, what brand of shoes are you looking for?\n")
            while(repeat):
                if "Nike" in shoes:
                     NikeModel = input("Which model are you looking for?\n")
                     if NikeModel in NikeModels_db.keys():
                           print("You can get them from " + ", Or ".join(shop for shop in NikeModels_db[NikeModel]))
                           repeat = false;
                else:
                    print("Sorry I dont know that model")
```